# Can't reference script from html template

Tags: javascript, html

This could look like a noob problem to some... I hope it is. I have a web app made using the php slim framework. I have the following hierarchy:

[image: app hierarchy]

I'm trying to reference script1.js from template1.phtml and script2.js from template2.phtml. I'm doing the following:

**template1.phtml**

```
<script src="app/scripts/script1.js"></script>
```

**template2.phtml**

```
<script src="app/scripts/script2.js"></script>
```

template1 works just as expected but template2, even when it's practically the same, gives the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/app/scripts/script2.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- Set the full script2.js path to the src (using a few ../) which obviously works but is not the right approach.

**NOTES**

- I'm using MAMP to test my app with php5.* When I run the app by using the command line and php7 both scripts are referenced properly.

Comment: Have you tried `../../scripts/script1.js`?

Comment: You might also try `/app/scripts/script1.js` if root_folder is indeed your web root.

Comment: try using script2.js inside template 1 and check if it's throwing any errors

Comment: Well, open the page source and click on the `<script src="app/scripts/script2.js"></script>`. You will see the path in the url

Comment: Because the 'subfolder' (where your html filed are) is already inside 'app' (the folder that your js files are in). You dont need to reference 'app'. do this instead...       `scripts/script1.js` . If that doesnt work reply to my comment and I will investigate further

Comment: @DatBoiTrump doesn't work either, when I do that it looks for ´http://localhost:8888/root_folder/template2/scripts/script2.js´ notice the "template2" part which must not be there... thanks in advance

Comment: RahulMeshram, KIKOSoftware, Vishwa, ZainFarooq thanks for your suggestions but sadly none of them has worked u.u

Comment: @JairoLozano Hey Jairo. So I've had another look. I make my own file directory exactly the same as yours, and referenced the "app/scripts/script2.js" path. And it worked? This gives me the idea that you may have tried to find this path somewhere else in your html, and thats where you got it wrong. Honestly, I am very confused and I have been doing this stuff for 6 years! Sorry if I couldnt help.

Comment: Well, thank you all for your time, apparently it has something to do with serving my app using MAMP, since when I serve my app using the php command (and choosing php 5) my references work just fine. I'm not happy since I didn't find the real reason, but at least I can keep developing my app.

Answer (score 0):

to reference script1.js from template1.phtml , you could use ../../../app/scripts/script1.js